# Using if else within mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'll keep this brief: can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?  The "else" section works, the if bit doesn't.

```
<?php

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_new WHERE id='" . $result['id_kit'] . "'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){

    if ($result['id_kit'] == 0) {

            ?>

            //DO THIS BIT IF $result['id_kit'] IS "0". 

            <?php
            }

    else {
            ?>

            //DO THIS BIT IF $result['id_kit'] IS ANYTHING OTHER THAN "0".  THIS BIT WORKS FINE

    <?php
    }
?>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: where is "if" statement?

Comment: What is `$result`? Did you mean to type `$row`?

Comment: this is far from clear... Could you post the entire (well styled) piece of code?

Comment: What 'if' but? Pleeeease format your code so it is readable!

Comment: Why do you end the php-part? You know you can write html in php like echo '<div style="background: url(images/nokit.jpg) no-repeat top right; height: 317px; width: 480px; float: right;">';

Comment: Hi all, I assume I must have issues on my machine because the code was perfectly readable for me. I have tried to tidy it up a bit and to just include the relevant parts.

Comment: $result is from a previous query that is already on the page, which is also being used for the 'else' statement that works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

Change

```
                    $sql2 = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM products_new WHERE id='" . $result ['id_kit'] . "'" );

                <?php 
                    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $sql2 ) ) {
```

To

```
                    $sql2 = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM products_new WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($result['id_kit']) . "'" );
                    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $sql2 ) ) {
```

Change

```
if ($result['id_kit'] == 0) {
```

To

```
if (empty($row)) {
```

You should have a working code

Thanks
:)

Comment: Hi Baba, thanks for your reply.  I did the changes as you suggested but no joy unfortunately, it stopped the code working entirely until I changed $_REQUEST to $result again.

Comment: Where are you getting your $result form ????? Can you post full code instead of partial code .. this way .. i would be able to help .. also try and for mat your code ...

Comment: Thanks, the whole code is now posted, formatted it as well as I can without re-writing the whole thing

Comment: i would look at it .. and get back to you in some mins

Comment: So may errors in your PHP code .. like using `<?php` inside another `<?php` tag ...update your code and post your output  ... thanks

Comment: If I don't have the <?php tags inside of each other my sql queries don't work properly as the first query is used to populate the other queries

Comment: The just use empty if (empty($row))  and also var_dump($row) to make sure you have a valid output

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)): ?>
    <?php if (statement): ?>
        some html here.
    <?php else: ?>
        some html.
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It's easier to read and understand.

And it does not work because `$result['id_kit'] != 0`

Comment: Have you checked your if with condition $result['id_kit'] != 0?